# What is the time complexity of a function that makes recursive calls (logarithmic) within a loop?

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, recurrence

Something like this -

```
func(n) {
    if (n == 1)
        return;
    else
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            func(n/2);
}
```

If you can provide a recurrence relation that would be awesome too.

Edit - If I use the master method, I think it works out like this -

a = 100, b = 2, *f* (n) = 1.

*f (n)* = *O* (n<sup>log<sub>2</sub>100 - *E*</sup>) for some constant *E* greater than 0, then *T* (n) = *O* (n<sup>log<sub>2</sub>100</sup>).

Comment: Have you looked at the [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms))?

Comment: If **you** can show your own efforts so far that would be *even more* awesome.

Comment: I have. I wasn't sure if it followed that form, but it looks like it does. Thanks for pointing that out to me.

Comment: This is not a homework problem, but I am working on a edit now with me applying the master method.

Comment: Result for `T(n)` looks correct ([Case 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Generic_form)). Not sure what you mean by `f(n) = O (n^[log2(100) - E])`, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: It's correct. By working on the properties of `n^log2(100)` you can put it in the form `100^log2(n)` which is easier to understand and came up as the solution when not using the master theorem .

Answer (score -1):

So with some help from the comments, after applying the master method the answer is in the edit to my original question.